# Changing the sample rate of audio recording in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audiocontext

Hi  I have a working **voice** recorder on a browser.  It implements navigator.getUserMedia and AudioContext
It records the sounds in .wav format - then converts to .mp3 and uploads the file.

The file sample rate is set to 44100Hz, and the mp3 output is resampled to 8000Hz.  The problem with is the amount of local storage needed to record a large audio file at this sample rate.  I am reducing the file size by converting to MP3, sample rate of 8000.
I read that the [sampleRate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/sampleRate) is readonly. So i guess the sample rate can be set on instantiation.  My question is how can I change the sample rate on an audio recorder with javascript?

nb. the code below has been trimmed to show the parts of interest.

```
    try{
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    audioCtx = new AudioContext;
    var buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, 8000, 8000);// this does not work!
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log('unable to create a audiocontext');
        exit;
    }
    navigator.getMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
                    console.log('No live audio input: ' + e);}
                );
    function startUserMedia(stream) {
        var input = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        console.log('Media stream created.' );
        console.log("input sample rate " +input.context.sampleRate);
        input.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        console.log('Input connected to audio context destination.');
        recorder = new Recorder(input);
        console.log('Recorder initialised.');
        var mediaStreamSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
        analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        var javascriptNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        mediaStreamSource.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
        javascriptNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = visualiser(analyser);
    }
```

Comment: This was some time ago, out of interest i ended up using the .ogg format, which works fine for voice.